# add row based on variable condition in R

Tags: r

I have df as follow

```
df
ID   type  other-col
1    A1      cc
1    A2      dd
1    A3      cc
2    A1      cc
2    B1      aa
3    A2      aa
```

I want add new to when "ID" changes with the value of F for "type" and "other-col" columns

```
new_df
ID
  df
    ID   type  other-col
    1    A1      cc
    1    A2      dd
    1    A3      cc
    1    F       F     <- this row added
    2    A1      cc
    2    B1      aa
    2    F       F      <- this row added
    3    A2      aa
```

how can I do it in R?
thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option with `group_split` and `add_row`.  We can split  by 'ID' with `group_split` into a list of data.frames, then loop through the `list` with `map`, add a row as the last row (`add_row` - by default adds row to the end, but we can control it with `.before` and `.after`), then `slice` out the `last` row as the last 'ID' didn't need the 'F' row

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   group_split(ID) %>% 
   map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
               add_row(ID = first(.$ID), type = 'F', `other-col` = 'F'))  %>%
   slice(-n())
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be doable in a single replacement operation once you know the indexes of where each change occurs. E.g.:

```
idx <- match(unique(df$ID), df$ID)[-1] - 1

df <- df[sort(c(sequence(nrow(df)),idx)),]
df[seq_along(idx) + idx, c("type","other_col")] <- "F"

#    ID type other_col
#1    1   A1        cc
#2    1   A2        dd
#3    1   A3        cc
#3.1  1    F         F
#4    2   A1        cc
#5    2   B1        aa
#5.1  2    F         F
#6    3   A2        aa
```

Where `df` was:

```
df <- read.table(text="ID   type  other_col
1    A1      cc
1    A2      dd
1    A3      cc
2    A1      cc
2    B1      aa
3    A2      aa", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach with a similar idea as @akrun's answer.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>% 
  split(f = .$ID) %>%
  map_if(.p = function(x) unique(x$ID) < max(dat$ID),
         ~bind_rows(.x, tibble(ID = unique(.x$ID), type = "F", `other.col` = "F"))) %>%
  bind_rows()

dat2
#   ID type other.col
# 1  1   A1        cc
# 2  1   A2        dd
# 3  1   A3        cc
# 4  1    F         F
# 5  2   A1        cc
# 6  2   B1        aa
# 7  2    F         F
# 8  3   A2        aa
```

**Data**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID   type  other-col
1    A1      cc
1    A2      dd
1    A3      cc
2    A1      cc
2    B1      aa
3    A2      aa",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Update**

I provided an updated answer to show that if `ID` column is not integer but character, we can create a new column (`ID2` in this case) that is converted to be factor based on `ID`, and then convert it to integer. The rest of the operation would be similar to the original answer but based on `ID2`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(ID2 = as.integer(factor(ID, levels = unique(.$ID)))) %>%
  split(f = .$ID2) %>%
  map_if(.p = function(x) unique(x$ID2) != unique(last(.)$ID2),
         ~bind_rows(.x, tibble(ID = unique(.x$ID), type = "F", `other.col` = "F",
                               ID2 = unique(.x$ID2)))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  select(-ID2)
dat2
#   ID type other.col
# 1  C   A1        cc
# 2  C   A2        dd
# 3  C   A3        cc
# 4  C    F         F
# 5  A   A1        cc
# 6  A   B1        aa
# 7  A    F         F
# 8  B   A2        aa
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID   type  other-col
C    A1      cc
C    A2      dd
C    A3      cc
A    A1      cc
A    B1      aa
B    A2      aa",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: the problem is that when ID column is not integer. then your code would not work

Comment: @Cina Thanks for your comment. I have updated my answer to show what to do when `ID` is not integer.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to akrun's answer but in base R. Basically, `split` dataframe by `ID` then `rbind` extra row to each split, then recombine dataframe and remove unrequired last row using `head(..., -1)` -

```
head(n = -1,
  do.call(rbind,
    lapply(split(dat, dat$ID), function(x) {
      rbind(x, c(x$ID[1], "F", "F"))
    })
  )
)

    ID type other.col
1.1  1   A1        cc
1.2  1   A2        dd
1.3  1   A3        cc
1.4  1    F         F
2.4  2   A1        cc
2.5  2   B1        aa
2.3  2    F         F
3.6  3   A2        aa
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R you could do:

```
 cbind(ID=sort(c(dat$ID,unique(dat$ID))),do.call(rbind,by(dat[-1],dat[1],rbind,'F')))

    ID type other.col
1.1  1   A1        cc
1.2  1   A2        dd
1.3  1   A3        cc
1.4  1    F         F
2.4  2   A1        cc
2.5  2   B1        aa
2.3  2    F         F
3.6  3   A2        aa
3.2  3    F         F
```

Or you could do:

```
do.call(rbind,by(dat,dat$ID,function(x)cbind(ID = unique(x[,1]),rbind(x[-1],"F"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inds = head(cumsum(with(rle(df$ID), unlist(lapply(lengths, function(i) c((rep(1, i)), F = 0))))), -1)
df1 = df[inds,]
df1[which(names(inds) == "F"), c("type", "other_col")] = "F"
df1
#    ID type other_col
#1    1   A1        cc
#2    1   A2        dd
#3    1   A3        cc
#3.1  1    F         F
#4    2   A1        cc
#5    2   B1        aa
#5.1  2    F         F
#6    3   A2        aa
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
m <- setDT(df)[, max(ID)]
df[, if (.BY$ID < m) rbind(.SD, as.list(rep("F", ncol(.SD)))) else .SD, ID]
```

output:

```
   ID type other-col
1:  1   A1        cc
2:  1   A2        dd
3:  1   A3        cc
4:  1    F         F
5:  2   A1        cc
6:  2   B1        aa
7:  2    F         F
8:  3   A2        aa
```

or if you dont mind adding another row at the bottom, code will be shorter: `setDT(df)[, rbind(.SD, as.list(rep("F", ncol(.SD)))), ID]`